# Checking if NSButton is down on drawRect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, drawrect, nsbutton

I would like to check if my custom NSButton is currently in a pressed state (the user is clicking down on it) in my custom drawRect method. Something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{
    if ([self buttonIsInPressedState]) {
        [[self alternateBGImage] drawInRect:dirtyRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0f];
    }else{
        [[self BGImage] drawInRect:dirtyRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0f];
    }
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

How would you check a thing like that? Is it possible?

**SOLUTION**

I ended up checking the mouseDownFlags on the buttons cell. Don't know if it's the "right" way to do it, so let me know if you have a better suggestion:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{        
    if ([self.cell mouseDownFlags] == 0) {
        [[self BGImage] drawInRect:dirtyRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0f];
    }else{
        [[self alternateBGImage] drawInRect:dirtyRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0f];
    }

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up checking the mouseDownFlags on the buttons cell. Don't know if it's the "right" way to do it, so let me know if you have a better suggestion. Solution is updated in the question above.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by checking `[self isHighlighted]`.

Comment: I was about to get very angry with life

Answer (score 3):

I don't think "`drawRect:`" is the right place to try to catch this.

You can subclass NSButton and then override either [`mouseDown:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/mouseDown%3a) or [`setState:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSButton/setState%3a) (looking for "`NSOnState`", which signifies the button is either selected or being pressed on).

Comment: I've tried self.state, but it only works for wether the button is "On" or "Off"! So the button is "On", once I've pressed it down AND released it. I want to check for if the use is CURRENTLY pressing down. MouseDown is also an option, but I can't get mouseUp to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([pBtn state]==NSOnState){
   NSLog(@" button Pressed ")
}else{
   NSLog(@" button not pressed ");

}
```

Comment: I've tried self.state, but it only works for wether the button is "On" or "Off"! So the button is "On", once I've pressed it down AND released it. I want to check for if the use is CURRENTLY pressing down.

Comment: Can you make use of Push button, its basically a toggle button, perhaps you can get what you want to achieve..

Comment: I tried. Doesn't work. I ended up doing the above. Let me know if you have a better solution.